# Running a nightly process with Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm writing an application using meteor and I need to run a process each night at a certain time. This process will need access to Meteor's Mongo database and would benefit from other Meteor features too.

Is it possible to run a meteor process or task of some sort on a scheduled basis? Or will I need to use a different stack to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a smartpackage called meteor-cron that can help you: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/cron.

Additionally if you want to go more manual you can use `Meteor.setInterval` ([docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_setinterval)) to run every hour and if its midnight to run your task.

Keep in mind if you use `meteor deploy` for meteor's free hosting, if no one visits your site it will go into a 'sleep mode' then wake up when the next user visits it. The user won't notice it but your meteor app won't be running to run these tasks.

Comment: Thanks Tarang! Does meteor-cron use a similar setInterval method behind the scenes i.e. will it also not fire if the hosting has sent the site to sleep?

Comment: @JonathanMoffatt yes it would use setInterval behind the scenes. It wont fire if the hosting site is sent to sleep. This is only meteor's free `deploy` hosting. If you host it yourself you won't run into this.